# Nginx redirect/rewrite a domain.a to domain.b/foo/ without changing a url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a problem with the implementation of such redirect:

```
https://domain.a/ => https://domain.b/foo/
```

without changing a url to domain.b. I would like to see the contents of the URL domain.a from domain.b/foo/ in browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Using [proxy pass](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) might works for you

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.a;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://domain.b/foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working - still show domain.b/foo in browser address bar, I would like to show domain.a with content from domain.b/foo.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example below :

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name     domain.a domain.b;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.a/ permanent;

    //Rest of your nginx configuration

    }
```

Comment: Thx but not working - still appears domain.b/foo in browser bar

Comment: From your question "Nginx redirect/rewrite domain.a to domain.b/foo/ without changing url", isn't it correct?

Comment: At the moment, after entering the domain.a appears in the address bar domain.b/foo/. I would like to after entering the domain.a appeared content from domain.b/foo/ without changing the address in my browser from domain.a to domain.b/foo/.

Comment: Okay, when you enter domain.a on browser, you should get the contents from domain.b/foo on browser. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly! and "you should get the contents from domain.b/foo on browser." without change url, I would like to domain.a was still visible in the address bar.

Comment: I have edited the rewrite rule. Please check now.

Comment: unfortunately, does not pass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51172/discussion-between-rajesh-keladimath-and-jboowie).

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply achieved by return as well.

```
location /{
   return 301 https://domain.b/foo/;
}
```